# Why absolute path in git project (xCode)

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

i have one small project, which is hosted on bitbucket.
I just switch computer and my project is broken.
as you can see below :

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/dev/iOS-dev/chanakya/Chanakya/../../../../../Al/Developer/BitBuck/Chanakya/Chanakya/leafContents.m'
>   clang: error: no input files
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

All the necessary files are there but seems like project somehow stored the absolute path of files rather than relative. As I just started working on new system, I m sure all the project will be broken.
Can anyone suggest me how can I fix current problem and how can I avoid this kind of problem in future.

Any help is very much appreciated.